# Batch cannot pull docker image from Artifact Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-artifact-registry

I use a workflow to create a batch job using a docker image hosted in a docker registry.

All of this happens within the same google cloud project.

My batch job fails with this error :

```
"docker: Error response from daemon: Head "https://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/entity/docker-registry/image-name/manifests/latest": denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/project-id/locations/us-west1/repositories/docker-registry" (or it may not exist).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

From [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/get-started) I understand that Compute Engine's service account doesn't have the `roles/artifactregistry.admin` : `Jobs default to using the Compute Engine default service account`

I get the same error after giving the role to the service account :

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-id \
--member=serviceAccount:compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/artifactregistry.admin
```

While digging service accounts I found another service another service account and also gave it the role : `service-xxxx@gcp-sa-cloudbatch.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

It does not solve the problem.

How can I see which service account is used ?

Can I see logs about denied permissions ?

Comment: Have you managed to check the below comment

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you are trying to push an image on a repository in which a specific hostname associated with its repository location is not yet authenticated and specified in the credential helper.You may refer to this [Setting up authentication for Docker](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication) .You may check and confirm the service account  to make sure you are still impersonating the correct one ,run below as mentioned in [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list)

```
gcloud auth list
```

> This command will show the active account, along with the other
> accounts that are authorized to access your Google Cloud project. The
> active account will be marked with an asterisk (*).

Try to run the authentication using a command specifying the location of your repository.You may try to run the configure-docker command against the auth group and see.

`gcloud auth configure-docker <location>-docker.pkg.dev`

And then try pulling the Docker image again.

Refer [Authenticating to a repository](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#auth) for more information and you can see these logs permission denied logs in [Cloud logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) for more details.

Comment: From what I understand this allow me to use compute engine service account to pull the image from my local machine. This won't allow me to pull the image from a batch job instance

Comment: It is the service account interacting with the Artifact registry should be given access to pull the images from the repo path so this should allow you to read the artifact.Please check the helpful documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#compute), [2](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/troubleshoot#pull) & [3](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account) for more information.